# Bind different action creator on different pages

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I got stucked with a problem with action creators that I think have a well known solution.

Suppose we have some React component `Foo` with a callback `onClick` which passed in props as usual.  We want to use action creator as the callback so we call [connect](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) with corresponding `mapDispatchToProps` and exporting the result:

```
// Foo.jsx
import someActionCreator from 'actions';

const Foo = props => {...} // Presentational React component

const mapStateToProps = state => ...;
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
    bindActionCreators(
        {
            onClick: someActionCreator
        },
        dispatch
    );
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Foo)
```

Now I want to use component `Foo` on one another page with different action creator passed as callback.  I can't provide any parameters to the module `Foo.jsx` at the time of import of course so I suppose I need to call `connect` right before the usage of `Foo` component now.  So this is my current solution:

```
// Foo.jsx

const Foo = props => {...} // Presentational React component

const mapStateToProps = state => ...;

const fooFabric = actionCreator => {
    const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch =>
        bindActionCreators(
            {
                onClick: actionCreator
            },
            dispatch
        );

    return connect(mapStateToProps , mapDispatchToProps)(Foo);
}

export default fooFabric;


// Page #1
import fooFabric from 'Foo';
import someActionCreator from 'actions';

const Foo = fooFabric(someActionCreator);
// render Foo


// Page #2
import fooFabric from 'Foo';
import someOtherActionCreator from 'actions';

const Foo = fooFabric(someOtherActionCreator);
// render Foo
```

This is the wheel I invented myself  :)  I believe this is a common problem and wonder if it has a better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why do you need to export `connect`ed component in this situation. You can export only `Foo.jsx` and connect it on a Page 1 & 2 e.g.

*Foo.jsx*

```
const Foo = ({ callback }) => (<div onClick={callback}>Hello</div>)
export default Foo;
```

*Page 1*

```
import Foo from 'Foo.jsx'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { myPageAction1 } from './actions'
...
const Page1ConnectedFoo = connect(mapStateToProps, { myPageAction1 })(Foo)
...
```

*Page 2*

```
import Foo from 'Foo.jsx'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { myPageAction2 } from './actions'
...
const Page2ConnectedFoo = connect(mapStateToProps, { myPageAction2 })(Foo)
```

Hope it make sense.

Comment: Thanks.  This looks like my current solution.  The difference is I hide `mapStateToProps` inside `fooFabric`.